# Modifying viewport visibility method for several linked objects at the same time

Tags: objects, 3d-view, linked-data

Is there a way to change viewport visibility method for several linked objects? I have many linked objects that show as `textured` now and would like to change that to `bounds`, but don't know hoe to do that apart from one by one. I can `select` all linked objects with Shift-L but when I try to change the `display as` property in' object properties' tab, only the active object is modified.

Comment: Hold down the Alt key while you're changing the setting.

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot!!